# How to train Keras model on Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, keras

I can train tensorflow models on google cloud machine learning engine. But when I use Keras code, I get error `No module named keras` on google cloud.

Answer (score 8):

I found out that in order to use keras on google cloud one has to install it with a setup.py script and put it on the same place folder where you run the gcloud command:

```
├── setup.py
└── trainer
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── cloudml-gpu.yaml
    ├── example5-keras.py
```

And in the setup.py you put content such as:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='example5',
  version='0.1',
  packages=find_packages(),
  description='example to run keras on gcloud ml-engine',
  author='Fuyang Liu',
  author_email='fuyang.liu@example.com',
  license='MIT',
  install_requires=[
      'keras',
      'h5py'
  ],
  zip_safe=False)
```

Then you can start your job running on gcloud such as:

```
export BUCKET_NAME=tf-learn-simple-sentiment
export JOB_NAME="example_5_train_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
export JOB_DIR=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME
export REGION=europe-west1

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
  --job-dir gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME \
  --runtime-version 1.0 \
  --module-name trainer.example5-keras \
  --package-path ./trainer \
  --region $REGION \
  --config=trainer/cloudml-gpu.yaml \
  -- \
  --train-file gs://tf-learn-simple-sentiment/sentiment_set.pickle
```

To use GPU then add a file such as `cloudml-gpu.yaml` in your module with the following content:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  # standard_gpu provides 1 GPU. Change to complex_model_m_gpu for 4 
GPUs
  masterType: standard_gpu
  runtimeVersion: "1.0"
```

Comment: How do I load the gs:// file in my python script?