# Tensorflow Keras API on Google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, keras, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I have a question on using tensorflow on google cloud platform.

I heard that Google cloud tensorflow doesnt support Keras (keras.io). However, now i can see that Tensorflow has its own API to access Keras (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras).

Given this, can I use the above mentioned API inside google cloud, since it is coming out along with Tensorflow package? Any idea sir?

I am able to access this API from the tensorflow installed on a anaconda machine.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1# Please try package-path option.
As per the docs...
-package-path=PACKAGE_PATH
"Path to a Python package to build. This should point to a directory containing the Python source for the job"
Try and give a relative path to keras from your main script.

More details here:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/ml-engine/local/train

Option 2# If you have a setup.py file
Inside your setup.py file within setup call pass argument install_requires=['keras']

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine does support Keras (keras.io), but you have to list it as a dependency when starting a training job. For some specific instructions, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322887/1399222), or a longer exposition on this [blog page](http://liufuyang.github.io/2017/04/02/just-another-tensorflow-beginner-guide-4.html). If you'd like to serve your model on Google Cloud Machine Learning or using [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/), then see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44232441/1399222) about exporting your model.

That said, you can also use [tf.contrib.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras), as long as you use the `--runtime-version=1.2` flag. Just keep in mind that packages in `contrib` are experimental and may introduce breaking API changes between versions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example on git which I saw was recenly added: 
[Keras Cloud ML Example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/keras)